# What is the best method to handle connection string in windows form application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, app-config

My C# application use `DataSet` and `TableAdapters`. They are generated form VS2008 GUI Tool.

Example:

> Right click project - > Add New Item - > DataSet

This method add a connection string automatically into `app.config`.

But this is hard corded method for connection string. I want to change the connection string in a easy way. But when I used data set, then connection string get from application property.
Are there any solution for this situation?

[image]

This is my connection string store in **Settings.Designer.cs** file

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "9.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(global::System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.ConnectionString)]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Data Source=SLCERT\\SQLEMK;Initial Catalog=TestDataBase;Integrated Security=True")]
        public string TestDataBaseConnectionString {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["TestDataBaseConnectionString"])); // this is the connection string get from the dataset's
            }
        }
    }
}
```

app.config contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings.TestDataBaseConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=SLCERT\SQLEMK;Initial Catalog=TestDataBase;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: And what application do is not easy way ?

Comment: what could be easier than editing app.config?

Comment: app.config accompanies your application.  its xml.  easily editable in any text editor

Comment: http://www.olegsych.com/2010/12/config-file-transformation/

Answer (score 6):

I believe that you ask this, so that you don't have to manually change between local testing and production/test server.

You might want to look at [How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

it's about web.config instead of app.config but it is the same idea.

ps. only for VS 2010 and above

Comment: Yes! I ask that.But now web application it is Windows Form Application

Comment: :) good guess then. More info here: http://mitasoft.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/multipleappconfig/ or here http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Other than the suggestion provided by JP Hellemons to do configuration transformations, there is something else you can do, as that is only supported (natively) by .NET 4.0. You can add any number of connection strings to the `<connectionStrings/>` section of a configuration file, so add a "DebugConnectionString" and a "ReleaseConnectionString", or similar.

Now, in order to use these without intervention each time environment is changed you can use trace constants. Say on local in Visual Studio you're compiling with the `DEBUG` constant set and when deploying for release it's not present, then you can do something like the following:

```
#if DEBUG 
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DebugConnectionString"];
#else
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReleaseConnectionString"];
#endif
```

Comment: This method OK,but when I used DataSet,I want to reconfigure each and every time before its release.(DataSet are genarated by vs2008 GUI tool,then it will automatically added connection string into settings.cs file)

Answer (score 2):

in app.config

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCS" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf;password=Password" 
        providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

and access  it like this

```
static string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString.ToString();
```

include

```
System.Configuration;
```

namespace

Comment: This is OK for general propose.But when I using DataSet(Dataset using GUI tool,VS automatically add connection string via settings file.I want to replace that part)

Comment: if you want to use the connection string in app.config. create a class  get the data from database store it in the class and call the class to  populate the control like datagridview.